# How to get websocket status using curl in C

Tags: c, curl, websocket

I'm using curl as a websocket client. I need to know when a connection has been closed.

At the moment the only way I can see an error code is when trying to read from the socket, gives me an error 56 (CURLE_RECV_ERROR) - which is not ideal. Anything else I can try?

I tried curl_easy_getinfo with CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS and CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET, but they didn't change after the socket was closed.

Here is the read code:

```
    while (1) {

        CURLcode result = curl_ws_recv(ws_curl, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &rlen, &meta);
        printf("===========> result=%d\r\n", result);      


        if (result == CURLE_OK) {
            ws_receiveCallbackFunction(string(buffer, rlen));
        }
        usleep(100000);
    }
```

And the log from curl itself which shows connection was reset:

```
===========> result=56

* Recv failure: Connection was reset

* OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
```

Comment: AFAIK, when it comes to server-client sockets connection, there is no way to tell if the server is alive or not, other than pinging it for reply. That's why we often use heartbeat mechanism to check the connection status.

Answer (score -1):

Read the [Control frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.html#section-5.5) section of the WebSocket RFC.

If you do not receive an explicit Close control frame, you should send ping packets periodically and expect a pong back. If you don't, or if you get a receive error, the other side has shut down their end of the websocket.

Comment: Thanks Botje. I can see curl is doing this in the background and curl internally does know the connection is reset. Would be great if I don't have to duplicate that
Here is logging from curl:
* reached easy.c:1231
* WS: 2 bytes left to decode
* WS:235 received FIN bit 1
* WS: received OPCODE PING
* WS: received 0 bytes payload (0 left, buflen was 2)
* WS: auto-respond to PING with a PONG, 0 bytes payload
* WS: send OPCODE PONG
* WS: set FIN
* WS: send FIN bit 1 (byte 8a)
* WS: send payload len 0
* WS: wanted to send 6 bytes, sent 6 bytes
* WS: bytesleft 0 datalen 0

Comment: The docuemntation states that curl automatically responds to incoming PING control frames with a PONG, as a good websocket implementation should. It also states that `curl_ws_recv` "Returns CURLE_GOT_NOTHING if the associated connection is closed. " Do you check for that?

Comment: I do check the value from curl_ws_recv, however it returns CURLE_RECV_ERROR, not CURLE_GOT_NOTHING. Internally it shows "connection reset" - not sure if that is the same as closed

Comment: "Connection reset" is a manifestation of the other side sending a TCP packet with the RST flag, which abruptly tears down the connection. Guess there's nothing better to do then.